# TinyMCE not loading in IE8

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

Yes I know it's 2016 and IE8 is older that my grandma but I have to support it for specific reasons.

My TinyMCE is not loading, it is version 4.4.1 in Wordpress 4.6.1 and when loading the Add new post screen in IE8 I get `Could not set the href property. Invalid property value` in tinymce.min.js and also `this.getDoc().body is null or not an object`

Is there a way of deregistering this script and enqueueing and older version?

Thanks

I have since discovered that TinyMCE loads fine is script_debug is false as default, but I need this to be true for my ACF color pickers to work so I have added the following to my themes functions.js

```
add_action('admin_init', 'unload_all_jquery');
function unload_all_jquery() {
    $jquery_ui = array(
        "iris",
    "wp-color-picker"
    );

    foreach($jquery_ui as $script){
        wp_dequeue_script($script);
    }
}

      add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_style' );
      function load_admin_style() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'irisacf', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/irisacf.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script('irisnew','http://SITEURL/wp-admin/js/iris.min.js?ver=1.0.7');
    wp_enqueue_script('colornew','http://SITEURL/wp-admin/js/color-picker.js?ver=4.6.1');
       }
```

And this is loading the files i've enqueued but is not removing iris and wp-color-picker from the scripts it's loading, in the source it has this line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://SITEURL/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-tabs,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sorta&amp;load%5B%5D=ble,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,iris,wp-color-picker,thickbox,underscore,shortcode,media-upload,back&amp;load%5B%5D=bone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,wp-plupload,mediaelement,wp-mediaelement,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-vie&amp;load%5B%5D=w,imgareaselect,image-edit,editor,quicktags,wp-a11y,wplink,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,wp-embed&amp;ver=4.6.1'></script>
```

Comment: but does it work on netscape4? ;) It is probably not supported anymore by microsoft so your quest is probably hopeless

Comment: .... older scripts might not work with new versions of wordpress. You can try download an old version of wordpress

Comment: OK I have just discovered that it works if I set script_debug to false, but I need it set to true for my color picker fields to work in IE8. If set to false, TinyMCE loads fine but my color picker fields then don't load.

Comment: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/system-requirements/

Comment: @NabilKadimi yes so it is compatible, and just discovered that it does work but when scripts_debug is true (so that other things work for me which didn't before) then it no longer works...

Comment: @Adrian Do you have some custom Javascript?

Comment: Nope, just the ACF plugin for my color pickers which dont load until script_debug is true

Comment: updated question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook `admin_init` is to early for dequeuing, use `wp_print_scripts`, see [examples in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script#Examples).

`define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );` will prevent combining dashboard scripts, so if that works for you on IE8, then do it for users with IE8:

```
/**
 * True if user browser is IE8.
 */
$is_IE8 = preg_match( '/(?i)msie 8/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );

/*
 * Disable combining dashboard scripts for people using IE8. 
 */
if( $is_IE8 ) {
    define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nabil, that's a handy snippet, unfortunately like I said enabling script_debug fixes my color picker field issue but then the TinyMCE doesn't work, disabling script_debug fixes TinyMCE but then breaks the color pickers...